# Insert values from arraylist into database

Tags: java, jdbc, arraylist

I use `addbatch()` and `executebatch()` to insert values from `ArrayList` into database.

But when I run the code this error message appeared:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'  
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2020)  
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1451)
```

This is the data:
1 A R1
7 A R1
2 B R1
3 C R1
4 B R1
8 A R1
5 A R1
9 C R1
6 C R1

This part of the code:

```
    public void insertDB(ArrayList<Eventlog> d) throws SQLException {  
        String insert = "insert into eventlog values(?,?,?)";  
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insert);  
        for (int k = 0; k < d.size()-1; k++) {  
            ps.setInt(1, d.get(k).getEvent_id()); // event id  
            ps.setString(3,d.get(k).getResources()); // resource  
            ps.setString(2,d.get(k).getActivity()); // activity  
            ps.addBatch();  
        }  
        ps.executeBatch();  
    }
```

Comment: The error is from your database telling you you're trying to insert a duplicate primary key. Is the event id a primary key, and is there already an event with id 5 in the database?

Comment: yes event id is the primary key and event id 5  is already in the database but I take these data from database and make some modification on it and then return it back to database

Comment: well then it's an update and not an insert. An insert operation always try to create a new record.

Comment: when i write update instead of insert it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine, but make sure your table is truncated before you run this since it looks like this is more or less a static set of fields.

To clarify further, primary key 5 already exists in your database and you need to delete it before running this code.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is evident that you are getting exception because you are trying to insert a duplicate key(5) in the table. If I understand correctly, as per your comment you are first getting the data from database and then changing it. Then you are trying to save this modified data to the database. So in this case you need to supply an update query instead of insert. Please try the following code:

```
   public void insertDB(ArrayList<Eventlog> d) throws SQLException {  
    String query = "update eventlog set resources = '?', activity = '?' where event_id = ?";  
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);  
    for (int k = 0; k < d.size()-1; k++) {              
        ps.setString(1,d.get(k).getResources()); // resource  
        ps.setString(2,d.get(k).getActivity()); // activity  
        ps.setInt(3, d.get(k).getEvent_id()); // event id  
        ps.addBatch();  
    }  
    ps.executeBatch();  
}
```

Please replace column names in `query` string with your actual column names from the database table.